# static variable in activity leads to memory leak?

Tags: java, android, memory, memory-leaks

i am not facing memory leak problem but i need to know how memory leak occurs. form [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html) the below code gives memory leak.

```
private static Drawable sBackground;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle state) {
  super.onCreate(state);

  TextView label = new TextView(this);
  label.setText("Leaks are bad");

  if (sBackground == null) {
    sBackground = getDrawable(R.drawable.large_bitmap);
  }
  label.setBackgroundDrawable(sBackground);

  setContentView(label);
}
```

can someone give me a full explanation of how the memory leak occurs ? and how the gc cannot collect the references ?.

and also plz explain whether  the below code leak memory ? , if it is  how it happens?

```
private static Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle state) {
      super.onCreate(state);

      TextView label = new TextView(context);
      label.setText("Leaks are bad");

      setContentView(label);
    }
```

Comment: I think the code is drawn from this blog [Avoid memory leaks on Android](http://www.curious-creature.org/2008/12/18/avoid-memory-leaks-on-android/). And that blog has also explain how the memory leaks occur.

Comment: i already read it, but i need to know how the garbage collector cannot able to collect the object,  When a Drawable is attached to a view, the view is set as a callback on the drawable. In the code snippet above, this means the drawable has a reference to the TextView which itself has a reference to the activity, so what is the exact problem when the gc trying to collect these objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how `GC` will run if you have the `reference` of the object. You have to release the object first.

> An Object becomes eligible for Garbage collection or GC if its not reachable from any live threads or any static references in other words you can say that an object becomes eligible for garbage collection if its all references are null.

Please read more here [How Garbage Collection works in Java](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/04/garbage-collection-in-java.html)

Also read this it will clarify your doubts about `GarbageCollector`

> Automatic garbage collection is the process of looking at heap memory, identifying which objects are in use and which are not, and deleting the unused objects. An in use object, or a referenced object, means that some part of your program still maintains a pointer to that object. An unused object, or unreferenced object, is no longer referenced by any part of your program. So the memory used by an unreferenced object can be reclaimed.

But in case of `static reference` you still have the reference of that object so the `GC` wont run on that object.

Read more here [What is Automatic Garbage Collection?](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html)